# unable to convert string resource name into resource

Tags: java, android, android-resources

I have an array of strings (for sound file names) , and i have the exact files attached to the projects as resources (raw), i am trying to fetch the ID of these resources via code in order to change which file (resource) to be playing from within the code.

```
  String[] phrasesDesc = {"doyouspeakenglish.m4a",
            "goodevening.m4a",
            "hello.m4a",
            "howareyou.m4a",
            "ilivein.m4a",
            "mynameis.m4a",
            "please.m4a",
            "welcome.m4a"
    };



       int index = 0;
        for (String str : phrasesDesc) {
            String res_name =phrasesDesc[index] ;
            resourceID[index] = this.getResources().getIdentifier(res_name, "raw", this.getPackageName());
            System.out.println(res_name +"               "+ resourceID[index]);
            index++;
        }
```

please help.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eXr9f.png)

Comment: I forgot to mention that when printing the values in array resourceID , all are 0

Comment: You need to remove the extensions from the filenames; e.g., just `"doyouspeakenglish"`.

Comment: thanks, actually i used similar code to write mine, but it does not work with me, all the time i am getting 0 as a resource ID..

Comment: Yeah, the code is right. You just need to remove the file extensions, which is what the linked answer is saying.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to query them without the file-type extension:

```
String[] phrasesDesc = {"doyouspeakenglish", "goodevening", "hello", "howareyou", "ilivein", "mynameis", "please", "welcome"};
```

or somehow strip the file-type extension, eg: `res_name.replace(".m4a", "")`.